# Split JSON to multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
"qtd_if": {"agreg": "First", "name": "IFs"},
"rnk_pib_tot": {"agreg": "Count","name": "PIB Tot"},
"rnk_pib_uf": {"agreg": "Sum", "name": "PIB UF"}
}
```

How can I have three Objects from the above JSON, being:

```
1st. Object
agr = {qtd_if : "First", rnk_pib_tot: "Count", rnk_pib_uf: "Sum"}

2st. Object
col = {0: qtd_if, 1: rnk_pib_tot, 2: rnk_pib_uf}

3st. Object
lab = {0: IFs, 1: PIB Tot, 2: PIB UF}
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicated properties in an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```js
// First convert your JSON to object with JSON.parse(),
// I use the object directly for brevity.
const sourceObject = {
    qtd_if: { agreg: "First", name: "IFs" },
    rnk_pib_tot: { agreg: "Count", name: "PIB Tot" },
    rnk_pib_uf: { agreg: "Sum", name: "PIB UF" },
};

const sourceObjectKeys = Object.keys(source);

const agr = {};
const col = {};
const lab = {};

sourceObjectKeys.forEach((key, i) => {
    agr[key] = sourceObject[key]['agreg'];
    col[i.toString()] = key;
    lab[i.toString()] = sourceObject[key]['name'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you deserialize the JSON, then you create variables referencing the parts you want to use.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"qtd_if": {"agreg": "First", "name": "IFs"},"rnk_pib_tot": {"agreg": "Count","name": "PIB Tot"},"rnk_pib_uf": {"agreg": "Sum", "name": "PIB UF"}}');

var agr = obj.qtd_if;
var col = obj.rnk_pib_tot;
var lab = obj.rnk_pib_uf;
```

Comment: The output was: var agr = {agreg: "First", name: "IFs"}, but I would like to have the Key and the value, like this: var agr = {qtd_if : "First", rnk_pib_tot: "Count", rnk_pib_uf: "Sum"}. For the var col I would like to have col = {0: qtd_if, 1: rnk_pib_tot, 2: rnk_pib_uf}, but I got Col {agreg: "Count", name: "PIB Tot"}. By the way, I know that I need to iteract over the JSOn to get all elemnts.